Retaining data in an edited file
Sony camera ARW file-type is set to RAW+jpg and is 24 MBs - then the edit, which includes crop, but result is a jpg under 1 MB. It needs to be at least HI res (3.5 MB). How do I ensure this?
edit
Thanks greatly for your comments.In response

I tried several editors; Photos, Adobe Express, and an on line conversion app. Only one crop.
only three textures of color; nightsky, sea, and full moon.
What defines resolution?
I am under the impression that a larger file will be better.

The image is to be transferred to a canvas as a wall hanging, approx 1200 x 80cms.

Can you mention the editor you use, what kind of edit you did, how much crop?

Does the image have solid areas of color, or is it a complex image? JPEG will compress solid areas of color quite efficiently.

This feels like an X-Y problem; resolution is not defined by the size of the file. Where does the 3.5 Mb requirement come from?

Does it need to be 3.5MB (megabytes - file size) or 3.5MP (megapixels resolution - number of pixels in the image)?

You seem to ask the wrong question. You ask how to create a big file, while it becomes clear that your real question seems to be "How do I create a file good enough to print at 1.2m long side? (You actually state 1200 cm, which would be 12m x 0.8m. I assume this is an error).
So let's sort this out:
What do you start with
Your Sony camera produces a 24 mega pixel image, which is 6000 x 4000 pixels in dimension. This is more than enough to produce billboard size prints.
You said, you shot RAW&JPG. You then end up with a sensor data RAW file (*.arw) and a JPG. If you proficient with developing a RAW, use that. If not, use the JPG.
But the file size?
If you save images of this size, you will end up with a file of between 5mb to 400kb. Depending on JPG maximum quality and lowest. JPG is a lossy file format, so you will loose a bit of detail if you use it, but on the high quality settings probably not really perceivable.
The size also depends on the image itself. Very detailed images tend to be worse at compression than images with large uniform areas.
What you need to understand though, is that the file size alone is not necessarily a good indicator of the image quality.
Note that with each cycle of loading, editing and saving the JPG file will get a bit worse as each save will recompress the image.
But you need high resolution
Resolution is the number of pixels per distance. So if you print your 6000 pixel width image at the size of an inch, you get 6000 dots per inch in that dimension. If you print it larger, you loose pixel density - also known as resolution.
If the long side is going to be printed at 1.2m you get a resolution of 6000 / 120cm = 50 pixel/cm or 127 pixels per inch.
There is a somewhat limited rule of thumb, that 300 dpi are a go to for high res printing. However, is is a pretty bad rule, as it is meant for single color letters and graphics - photos can look really good with way less. Plus the rule is excluding the viewing distance from the equation: Are you looking at the image at nose to surface level? If not, you have more wiggling space.
See this here for some more details:
Is there a general formula for image size vs. print size?
So what should I give to the printer?
Give them the image cropped as you have it, as max quality jpg. They will scale it to fit. And if they know what they are doing, the will warn you if there is a resolution problem. If you want to make absolutely sure that no details are lost, give them a TIF with zip compression. That is absolutely lossless.
By cropping you are discarding part of the image, so you will of course work with the remaining pixels. If you are cropping to a very small part of the image, you can end up with an image that is no longer suited for large format printing. Your print service should warn you, if that is the case.
In this case you can use software like Topaz Gigapixel or others to try to blow up the image and insert a good interpolation or "guess" of the details that should be there. But I advise you to not even look at these tools unless you are sure you need them.
Regarding your other remarks

While you may have used different photo editors, most of them should be able to crop an image. Unless we know which you want to use, we cannot tell you how to do that. Please feel free to open a new question for that.

It sounds a bit that you are cropping to a round format. The reason not all editors do this is that image files are not round. They can have a round image in a rectangular file giving the illusion of a round image by either having white background or transparency. If you print it, the paper will just stay white. So in some editors you may just need to select a circle, reverse the selection and fill that area with white to achieve a "round crop".

I don't understand, what you mean with textures in this context

See the text above about resolution

A larger file has more storage room for information, but is not per se better. Having room does not mean needing or even using the room. I can save a 64x64 pixel icon as 6400x6400pixels, generating a huge file, but it will look worse in printing, as the details and sharp contrasts may get mushy, depending on how the enlargement is done. Unless you know what you are doing, the original file holds the most information.



This sounds like the issue of a misinformed client requiring a large file in terms of byte size thinking that directly relates to resolution and print size... the two are not directly related.
Also, the "ARW file type" cannot be raw+jpeg... it can only be raw; there will be a separate jpeg recorded as well.
When converting a raw file you are taking (up to) 14bit data (raw format) and converting it to 8bit data (jpeg format)... that is a lot of data compression; even with no other edits/compression/etc applied.

Also, the "ARW file type" cannot be raw+jpeg... it can only be raw; there will be a separate jpeg recorded as well. Unless they edit the embedded thumbnail. I don't know for Sony but in Canon CR2s there is small 160x120 thumbnail and a much bigger 2MB one (full size image, JPEG of moderate quality (85 IIRC)). So an application that looks directly for JPEG headers could therefore open the RAW like a JPEG.

@xenoid, there are usually several programs that can open the raw file with the jpeg settings applied; usually the OEM software as a minimum. And all raw files include some level of jpeg preview; but an AWR file is still a raw file.
